# Convert HEX iTunes Persistent ID to High and Low 32-bit forms

Tags: javascript, itunes, hex

On a Mac, I can extract the "Persistent ID" for a particular song from the "iTunes Music Library.xml" file and then use Applescript to play that song like so:

```
tell application "iTunes"   
    set thePersistentId to "F040658A7687B12D"
    set theSong to (some track of playlist "Music" whose persistent ID is thePersistentId)  
    play theSong with once  
end tell
```

On a PC, I can extract the "Persistent ID" from the XML file in the same way.  The documentation for the iTunes COM interface says the function "ItemByPersistentId" has two parameters: "highID" (The high 32 bits of the 64-bit persistent ID) and "lowID" (The low 32 bits of the 64-bit persistent ID).   but I can't figure out how to convert the hex-based value to the high and low 32-bit values the ItemByPersistentId function wants.

```
var thePersistentId = "F040658A7687B12D";  
var iTunes = WScript.CreateObject("iTunes.Application"); 
var n = parseInt(thePersistentId);  
var high = (do something with n?);  
var low = (do something else with n?);  
iTunes.LibraryPlaylist.tracks.ItemByPersistentId(high,low).play();
```

Comment: Do you have a specific example ID so code can be tried and tested?

Comment: Example Persistent IDs in iTunes: F040658A7687B12D, 9CA9C40E86124232, 1489F2F36DA31F95 (they are all 16 characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the situation is on the windows script host, but some JS clients have a 32 bit int, so your `var n = parseInt(thePersistentId);` is doubly troublesome. You should always include the base when using parseInt (e.g. `parseInt(hexValue, 16)`, `parseInt(octValue, 8)`).

To avoid 32 bit script interpreter limitations, you can extract the lower 32 bits and upper 32 bits seperately. Each hex digit is 4 bits, so the lower 32 bits are the last 8 characters of your persistent ID, and the upper 32 bits are the remaining 8 (unless it has the `0x` prefix, then it's the next rightmost chunk of 8 characters).

```
var hexId = "XXXXX";   
var iTunes = WScript.CreateObject("iTunes.Application");  

//the following two statements assume you have a valid 64 bit hex, 
//you may want to verify the length of the string

//grab and parse the last 8 characters of your string
var low = parseInt(hexId.substr(hexId.length - 8), 16);
//grab and parse the next last 8 characters of your string
var high = parseInt(hexId.substr(hexId.length - 16, 8), 16);
iTunes.LibraryPlaylist.tracks.ItemByPersistentId(high,low).play();
```

Edit: From what I've read in the [iTuner source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Development/iTuner/iTuner/iTunes/PersistentID.cs.htm), it looks like `highID` is actually the upper 4 bytes, and `lowID` the lower 4 bytes, not 8 bytes (thus discarding the middle 8 bytes of the `persistentID`...). Here's a modified attempt:

```
//assumes hex strings with no "0x" prefix
//grab and parse the last 4 characters of your string
var low = parseInt(hexId.substr(hexId.length - 4), 16);
//grab, pad and parse the first 4 characters of your string
var high = parseInt(hexId.substr(0, 4) + "0000", 16);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Good thought.  Unfortunately, ItemByPersistentId returns a "Overflow" error with the high/low computed this way.  I'm using hexId="F040658A7687B12D" as my test case. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @cloudbrain, I dug around, and it looks like the highID is the upper 4 bytes as the top bits in an 8 byte integer, and lowID is the lowest 4 bytes. Try my modification above, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: How would you go about converting the high and low to a string?

Comment: String.Format("{0}{1}", _high.ToString("X"), _low.ToString("X"));

Comment: @mike, well, it's javascript, so either simply append them to a string or call `.toString`. See [What's the best way to convert a number to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string) for more information.