# What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, performance, numbers

What's the "best" way to convert a number to a string (in terms of speed advantage, clarity advantage, memory advantage, etc) ?

Some examples:

1. `String(n)`
2. `n.toString()`
3. `""+n`
4. `n+""`

Comment: This question to me seems clear enough.

Answer (score 749, accepted):

like this:

```
var foo = 45;
var bar = '' + foo;
```

Actually, even though I typically do it like this for simple convenience, over 1,000s of iterations it appears **for raw speed there is an advantage for `.toString()`**

See Performance tests here (not by me, but found when I went to write my own):
http://jsben.ch/#/ghQYR

Fastest based on the JSPerf test above: `str = num.toString();`

*It should be noted* that the difference in speed is not overly significant when you consider that it can do the conversion any way **1 Million times in 0.1 seconds**.

**Update:** The speed seems to differ greatly by browser.  In Chrome `num + ''` seems to be fastest based on this test http://jsben.ch/#/ghQYR

**Update 2:** Again based on my test above it should be noted that Firefox 20.0.1 executes the `.toString()` about 100 times slower than the `'' + num` sample.

Comment: There are cases where the conversion may not return a preferable answer: `'' + 123e-50` returns `"1.23e-48"`.

Comment: This answer does not seem to be true anymore if you look at http://jsperf.com/number-to-string/2.
Might be worth updating it :)

Comment: @hongymagic: that answer is in fact the only conceivable: the number does not care nor know how it was entered, and the standard printed representation is with exactly one digit before the dot.

Comment: I ran the test in http://jsben.ch/ghQYR, every time it shows me a different result!

Comment: I like this answer because a `null foo` doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @MaryamSaeidi: Using **drublic**'s _jsperf.com_ test above seems more consistent.

Comment: jsperf is way better than jsben. jsben is pretty and it shows up in google results now, but it's useless for accuracy.

Comment: Simply for exhaustivity you can also use JSON.stringify() which is almost as fast as .toString()

Comment: As an updated version of this answer, i've ran some test using the same benchmark as you, but in addition of ES6 string template. And turns out it's a close match ! ( https://jsben.ch/RkGXi )  This might be a more elegant way of converting number to string.

Comment: Please, note that if the number is -0 then the result will be 0 without the negative sign.

Comment: The results are much different when used in a loop though, anyway one should probably benchmark the specific use case where performance is required. See https://jsben.ch/7cxUW

Comment: Yes it seems to change too depending on if you need to add the number into a string with other content (prepend/append etc.) https://jsben.ch/6UJop

Answer (score 508):

In my opinion `n.toString()` takes the prize for its clarity, and I don't think it carries any extra overhead.

Comment: It does carry some overhead even though it's insignificant in recent browser versions. In Firefox Quantum at least

Comment: This is unsafe. n might be null or undefined.

Comment: @david.pfx the question asks how to convert numeric values to a string. Providing examples of non-numeric values (e.g. `null`, `undefined`) that don't work with this answer hardly makes it "unsafe".

Comment: @MichaelMartin-Smucker: If you write a lot of JS you realise that things are rarely so cut and dried. The question was open and IMO a good answer should at least acknowledge the issue of a string that is actually null or undefined. YMMV.

Comment: @david.pfx I have written a LOT of js and I do not remember the last time where I needed a number as a string and anything but a number as a string would have sufficed. This is the correct answer. There is no answer to handling `null` or `undefined` as it is application specific, whilst I imagine `(n || defaultNumber).toString() ` is what most people would want in such a situation I strongly disagree we should be working it into all questions. This was about converting numbers to strings, good architecture and other type conversions where needed are separate lessons.

Comment: @david.pfx what certainty? my point was there is no answer to `null` or `undefined`, not throwing an error isn't handling it and hiding it will also cause "code to fail". I don't appreciate your condescending statements like "perhaps it's time to write less code and read more", I advise you to keep ad hominem out of your argument and will happily look past it this time.

Comment: @david.pfx `'' + undefined` will give you `'undefined'` which is hardly any better in my opinion, if not worse as it fails silently. The same with `('' + null) === 'null'`

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk: Better by what metric? A good answer should have been longer and considered the possibility of non-numeric. Whether or how to deal with non-numeric values will depend on context, and in some of those contexts `''+value` is better. YMMV.

Comment: would this `n?.toString()` address the above issues?

Comment: @david.pfx Some companies do write JS code that is very much cut and dried. It depends on many things like industry, frameworks, type of project, tasks, etc. Perhaps input data is presented as a rigidly validated object. Perhaps it's TypeScript and types are set in stone across the codebase.

Comment: 5.toString() will not work. Therefor it allows additional errors to arise, not a good option.

Answer (score 117):

Explicit conversions are very clear to someone that's new to the language.  Using type coercion, as others have suggested, leads to ambiguity if a developer is not aware of the coercion rules.  Ultimately developer time is more costly than CPU time, so I'd optimize for the former at the cost of the latter.  That being said, in this case the difference is likely negligible, but if not I'm sure there are some decent JavaScript compressors that will optimize this sort of thing.

So, for the above reasons I'd go with: `n.toString()` or `String(n)`.  `String(n)` is probably a better choice because it won't fail if `n` is null or undefined.

Comment: The question was about converting numbers, not about converting numbers, or `null`, or `undefined`. If `n` is `null` or `undefined` due to a bug in my program, then I'd prefer my program to fail in this state, to give me a better chance of finding and fixing the bug. Program crashes are gifts to the programmer, to help her find the bugs :-). The alternative is to deliver software that does not work as designed, having carefully glossed over the bugs. So, I'm not a fan of using `String(n)` to mask an error.

Comment: `String(n)` is good for using in a functional style, e.g. with underscore's combine `_.compose(funcThatNeedsAStringParam, String)`.

Comment: String(null) won't crash the progam, but it will return the literal string "null", which is probably not what you want.  If the data could legitimately be null, then you need to handle it explicitly.

Comment: @MattWallis I think that should be the decision of the developer, not the answerer, don't you think?

Answer (score 57):

The below are the methods to convert an `Integer` to `String` in JS.

The methods are arranged in the decreasing order of performance.

```
var num = 1
```

**Method 1:**

```
num = `${num}`
```

**Method 2:**

```
num = num + ''
```

**Method 3:**

```
num = String(num)
```

**Method 4:**

```
num = num.toString()
```

**Note:** You can't directly call `toString()` on a number. `2.toString()` will throw `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

(The performance test results are given by [@DarckBlezzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730371/6904888) in his answer)

Comment: You can use `2..toString()`. Notice the double periods.

Comment: @RonMartinez Interesting behaviour

Answer (score 51):

Other answers already covered other options, but I prefer this one:

```
s = `${n}`
```

Short, succinct, already used in many other places (if you're using a modern framework / ES version) so it's a safe bet any programmer will understand it.

Not that it (usually) matters much, but it also seems to be [among the fastest](https://jsperf.com/number-to-string/76) compared to [other methods](https://jsperf.com/number-to-string/53).

Comment: It's also safe if n might be not a number.

Comment: But so is `n.toString()` then, isn't it?

Comment: @amn if `n` is `undefined` it will throw a syntax error by using `.toString()`

Comment: Doesn't this just give the same result as `String(n)` in all cases? The only difference is that it's less clear.

Comment: And much slower.

Comment: If `n` is `undefined`, `\`${n}\`` returns string `'undefined'`. Better would be `\`${n || ''}\`` which returns an empty string if `n` is `undefined` or `null`. **Attention**: it also returns an `''` if `n = 0`. More complex (and slower) but returning `'0'` instead of an empty string: `\`${!isNaN(n) ? n : n || '' }\``

Comment: @AdrianBartholomew - Just out of interest, why do you say it is much slower? Apparently, it is much faster, or the fastest, according to [these results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730371/4424636) - see the results for test 4.

Answer (score 41):

> ...JavaScript's parser tries to parse
>   the dot notation on a number as a floating point literal.

```
2..toString(); // the second point is correctly recognized
2 .toString(); // note the space left to the dot
(2).toString(); // 2 is evaluated first
```

[Source](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#object.general)

Answer (score 21):

*Tongue-in-cheek obviously:*

```
var harshNum = 108;
"".split.call(harshNum,"").join("");
```

Or in ES6 you could simply use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

```
var harshNum = 108;
`${harshNum}`;
```

Comment: If I run the benchmarks with ES6 templates, it sometimes even proves to be faster than the `'' + number` method. This said, the results of these benchmarks varies a lot when performing them multiple times so not sure if they should be taken too serious.

Answer (score 16):

I used https://jsperf.app to create a test case for the following cases:

```
number + ''
`${number}`
String(number)
number.toString()
```

https://jsperf.app/yineye

As of 24th of July, 2018 the results say that `number + ''` is the fastest in Chrome, in Firefox that ties with template string literals.

Both `String(number)`, and `number.toString()` are around 95% slower than the fastest option.

[image: performance tests, description above]

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to convert any variable to a string is to add an empty string to that variable.

```
5.41 + ''    // Result: the string '5.41'
Math.PI + '' // Result: the string '3.141592653589793'
```

Comment: Note that it needs to be inside parens: `(5.41 + '')` to use the String methods like `.substring()` and others

Comment: Why does that need to be noted?

Answer (score 12):

I recommended [`` `${expression}` ``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) because you don't need to worry about errors.

```js
[undefined,null,NaN,true,false,"2","",3].forEach(elem=>{
  console.log(`${elem}`, typeof(`${elem}`))
})

/* output
undefined string
null      string
NaN       string
true      string
false     string
2         string
          string
3         string
*/
```

---

Below you can test the speed. but the order will affect the result. (in StackOverflow) you can test it on your platform.

```js
const testCases = [
  ["${n}", (n) => `${n}`], // 
  ['----', undefined],

  [`"" + n`, (n) => "" + n],
  [`'' + n`, (n) => '' + n],
  [`\`\` + n`, (n) => `` + n],
  [`n + ''`, (n) => n + ''],
  ['----', undefined],

  [`String(n)`, (n) =>  String(n)],
  ["${n}", (n) => `${n}`], // 

  ['----', undefined],
  [`(n).toString()`, (n) => (n).toString()],
  [`n.toString()`, (n) => n.toString()],

]

for (const [name, testFunc] of testCases) {
  if (testFunc === undefined) {
    console.log(name)
    continue
  }
  console.time(name)
  for (const n of [...Array(1000000).keys()]) {
    testFunc(n)
  }
  console.timeEnd(name)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to re-edit this with more data when I have time to, for right now this is fine...

**Test in nodejs v8.11.2: 2018/06/06**

```js
let i=0;
    console.time("test1")
    for(;i<10000000;i=i+1){
     const string = "" + 1234;
    }
    console.timeEnd("test1")
    
    i=0;
    console.time("test1.1")
    for(;i<10000000;i=i+1){
     const string = '' + 1234;
    }
    console.timeEnd("test1.1")
    
    i=0;
    console.time("test1.2")
    for(;i<10000000;i=i+1){
     const string = `` + 1234;
    }
    console.timeEnd("test1.2")
    
    i=0;
    console.time("test1.3")
    for(;i<10000000;i=i+1){
     const string = 1234 +  '';
    }
    console.timeEnd("test1.3")
    
    
    i=0;
    console.time("test2")
    for(;i<10000000;i=i+1){
     const string = (1234).toString();
    }
    console.timeEnd("test2")
    
    
    i=0;
    console.time("test3")
    for(;i<10000000;i=i+1){
     const string = String(1234);
    }
    console.timeEnd("test3")
    
    
    i=0;
    console.time("test4")
    for(;i<10000000;i=i+1){
     const string = `${1234}`;
    }
    console.timeEnd("test4")
    
    i=0;
    console.time("test5")
    for(;i<10000000;i=i+1){
     const string = 1234..toString();
    }
    console.timeEnd("test5")
    
    i=0;
    console.time("test6")
    for(;i<10000000;i=i+1){
     const string = 1234 .toString();
    }
    console.timeEnd("test6")
```

**output**

```
test1: 72.268ms
test1.1: 61.086ms
test1.2: 66.854ms
test1.3: 63.698ms
test2: 207.912ms
test3: 81.987ms
test4: 59.752ms
test5: 213.136ms
test6: 204.869ms
```

Comment: Yay - test4 is what I regularly use!!

Comment: Can the test be more time precise? On my PC test take between 0.7000ms and 10.000 ms. Test 2 does some caching, as it becomes faster. All other times seem to fluctuate.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to **format** the result to a specific **number of decimal places,** for example to represent currency, you need something like the `toFixed()` method.

```
number.toFixed( [digits] )
```

`digits` is the number of digits to display after the decimal place.

Comment: Unsafe unless you *know* it's a number.

Answer (score 4):

**The only** valid solution for **almost all** possible existing and future cases (input is number, null, undefined, Symbol, anything else) is `String(x)`. Do not use 3 ways for simple operation, basing on value type assumptions, like "here I convert definitely number to string and here definitely boolean to string".

Explanation:

`String(x)` handles nulls, undefined, Symbols, [anything] and calls `.toString()` for objects.

`'' + x` calls `.valueOf()` on x (casting to number), throws on Symbols, can provide implementation dependent results.

`x.toString()` throws on nulls and undefined.

Note: `String(x)` will still fail on prototype-less objects like `Object.create(null)`.

If you don't like strings like 'Hello, undefined' or want to support prototype-less objects, use the following type conversion function:

```
/**
 * Safely casts any value to string. Null and undefined are converted to ''.
 * @param  {*} value
 * @return {string}
 */
function string (str) {
  return value == null ? '' : (typeof value === 'object' && !value.toString ? '[object]' : String(value));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With number literals, the dot for accessing a property must be distinguished from the decimal dot. This leaves you with the following options if you want to invoke to String() on the number literal 123:

```
123..toString()
123 .toString() // space before the dot 123.0.toString()
(123).toString()
```

Comment: Basically interesting to see this is possible. But apart from that, what's a beneficial use case for doing this conversion rather than just writing `"123"` in the first place? I don't even see this case explicitly listed in OPs question. As a rule of thumb: if you now the literal value, just put it in quotes for there is no processing required at all.

Answer (score 2):

I like the first two since they're easier to read. I tend to use `String(n)` but it is just a matter of style than anything else.

That is unless you have a line as

```
var n = 5;
console.log ("the number is: " + n);
```

which is very self explanatory

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the situation but anyway you can use the `.toString()` method as it is very clear to understand.

Answer (score 2):

.toString() is the built-in typecasting function, I'm no expert to that details but whenever we compare built-in type casting verse explicit methodologies, built-in workarounds always preferred.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to take everything into consideration, I will suggest following

```
var myint = 1;
var mystring = myint + '';
/*or int to string*/
myint = myint + ''
```

IMHO, its the fastest way to convert to string. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Method `toFixed()` will also solves the purpose.

```
var n = 8.434332;
n.toFixed(2)  // 8.43
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are curious as to which is the most performant check this out where I compare all the different Number -> String conversions.

Looks like `2+''` or `2+""` are the fastest.

https://jsperf.com/int-2-string

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) constructor. According to [this benchmark](http://jsben.ch/ghQYR) it's the fastest way to convert a Number to String in Firefox 58 even though it's slower than 
`" + num` in the popular browser Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Number` object and then call `toString()`.

`Number.call(null, n).toString()`

You may use this trick for another javascript native objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just come across this recently, method 3 and 4 are not appropriate because how the strings are copied and then put together. For a small program this problem is insignificant, but for any real web application this action where we have to deal with frequency string manipulations can affects the performance and readability.

[Here is the link the read](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems similar results when using node.js. I ran this script:

```
let bar;
let foo = ["45","foo"];

console.time('string concat testing');
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    bar = "" + foo;
}
console.timeEnd('string concat testing');


console.time("string obj testing");
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    bar = String(foo);
}
console.timeEnd("string obj testing");

console.time("string both");
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    bar = "" + foo + "";
}
console.timeEnd("string both");
```

and got the following results:

```
❯ node testing.js
string concat testing: 2802.542ms
string obj testing: 3374.530ms
string both: 2660.023ms
```

Similar times each time I ran it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax:

```
`${this.num}`
```