# converting values property to string in javascript in an object

Tags: javascript, html, string, key-value

I want the value in the key value object to be converted to a string i.e., 
lets say I have object keyValue where, `

```
var keyValue = { A : 20, b : 210 , 1 :30 , 3 : 322};
```

my converted object should be

```
var keyValue = {A : '20', b : '210' , 1 :'30' , 3 : '322' };
```

As you can see all the numbers are converted to strings. Please help me achieve this.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string

Comment: That seems to be a very simple task. What are you having problems with? Iterating over the object? Converting a number to a string? Assigning a value to a property?

Comment: converting a number to string.

Comment: i was basically thinking of a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the conversion code in [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string?lq=1) in a loop:

```
for (var key in keyValue) {
    if (keyValue.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // skip inherited properties
        keyValue[key] = '' + keyvalue[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

iterate over each key value pair with a for loop, and use `.toString` method

```
var keyValue = { A : 20, b : 210 , 1 :30 , 3 : 322};
for (var k in keyValue) {
    keyValue[k] = keyValue[k].toString();
}
console.log(keyValue);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5JwbV/