# Trying to make a clock in JavaScript, getting an error, Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

Clock script is very basic, I have:

```
function time() {
  var time = new Date().getTime();
  var ms = time.substring(11, 13)
  var secs = time.substring(0, 10)
}
```

When using `substring`, it returns the error "undefined is not a function"
I need a way to get that "time" value to be set to the actual returned number, not the `new Date().GetTime();` returning it.

Comment: Do a `console.log(typeof time)`.

Comment: @FelixKling How would that work?

Comment: numbers don't have substring()

Comment: Exactly. Number values don't have a `substring` method. Only strings have such a method. Hence you get that error. Did you expect `getTime` to return a string or did you expect every data type to have a `substring` method?

Comment: @FelixKling But can't you turn that number into a string?

Comment: But why would you, when you can get all the parts of the date with built-ins

Comment: Of course you can: [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5765398/218196)

Comment: @adeneo Well, I'm challenging myself

Comment: Wouldn't it be more challenging to use the [**proper**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds) methods ?

Comment: If your operation involves converting a date to a string before parsing, then using the substring method, you're not going about it the right way. Look at all the various methods of the Date object. These should give you the part of the date/time you want.

Comment: If you want unix time in seconds, you'd rather do `var secs = time / 1000;`.

Comment: For what you appear to be doing, as @adeneo and @Robusto alluded to, it would be better to use `.getMilliseconds`, `.getSeconds`, etc. `.getTime` returns an ever-increasing integer. Eventually that number will get a digit longer and all of your sub-string offsets will be broken. Also as a side note, instead of creating a new `Date` object and calling `.getTime` on it you could just use [`Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `substring()` because the time isn't a string. Convert it to a string first:

```
var time = ''+(new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: Why would I convert it into a string when I could just do arithmetic on the number to start with?

Comment: IDK because thats what the OP wanted to do - a subString operation on a number. so its obvious you convert that to string to do a string operation. OP din't seem to wanna do arithmetic!

Comment: No--he clearly wants to calculates `secs` and `ms`. String manipulation was merely his flawed initial approach.

Answer (score 0):

As of now I have finished that script, XD it's much better than those ones.

Here's HTML the code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"/>
<script>setInterval(time,1);var a,b,c,d,x,y;function time(){'use strict';x=new Date();y=Date().toString().split(' ');a='day day sday nesday rsday day urday';b='uary ruary ch il  e y ust tember ober ember ember';if(x.getHours()>11){d='P.M.';c=x.getHours()-12;}else{d='A.M.';c=x.getHours()};if(c==0){c=12};document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=y[0]+ a.split(' ')[x.getDay()]+', '+y[1]+b.split(' ')[x.getMonth()]+' '+x.getDate()+', '+x.getFullYear()+'; '+c+':'+y[4].split(':')[1]+':'+y[4].split(':')[2]+'.'+x.getTime().toString().substring(10,13)+' '+d;};</script>
<span onload="time()" id="time" style="font-family:Open Sans;font-size:18px;text-align:center;margin:3% 3% 3% 3%;padding:2% 2% 2% 2%;box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px silver;border:1px solid gray"/>
```