# How to implement toString to convert a number to a string?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, tostring

I was asked during an interview to implement `toString()` to convert a number into a string.

`toString()
n => s
123 => "123"`

Aside from:

- converting the number by concatenating an empty string 
  `123+""`
- using the native `toString()` function
  `(123).toString()`
- creating a new string 
  `String(123)`

How else could `toString()` be implemented in javascript?

Comment: Probably by dividing by 10 and taking the result modulo 10 repeatedly…

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @Xufox how does that work? i'm lost. without casting wouldn't you need to get a utf code or something?

Comment: [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3389287/4642212) but with integer division. You could then add `48` to the digits and use `String.fromCharCode` to get a string value of the number.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(n)` would work.

Comment: `"".slice.apply(123)`, `[].join.apply([123])` etc

Comment: Thanks for answers to this question. There are many correct ways to solve this problem, so I'll wait until there is a large enough vote for any one answer to accept as the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as the property name of an object.

```js
function toString(value) {
  // Coerces value to a primitive string (or symbol)
  var obj = {};
  obj[value] = true;
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)[0];
}
console.log(toString(123));  // 123      -> "123"
console.log(toString(1.23)); // 1.23     -> "1.23"
console.log(toString(NaN));  // NaN      -> "NaN"
console.log(Infinity);       // Infinity -> "Infinity"
console.log(toString(-0));   // -0       -> "0"
console.log(toString(1e99)); // 1e99     -> "1e+99"
```

You can also use DOM attributes:

```
var obj = document.createElement('div');
obj.setAttribute('data-toString', value);
return obj.getAttribute('data-toString');
```

Or join an array

```
return [value].join();
```

And a big etcetera. There are lots of things which internally use the [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring) abstract operation.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to consider a number as a series of digits. This is not an inherent property of numbers, since the base-10 representation that we use is quite arbitrary. But once a number is represented as a series of digits, it is quite easy to convert each digit individually to a string, and concatenate all such strings.

EDIT: As pointed out, this only takes integers into consideration (which is probably acceptable for an interview question).

```
var intToDigits = function(n) {
    var highestPow = 1;
    while (highestPow < n) highestPow *= 10;
    var div = highestPow / 10;

    // div is now the largest multiple of 10 smaller than n

    var digits = [];

    do {
        var digit = Math.floor(n / div);
        n = n - (digit * div);
        div /= 10;
        digits.push(digit);
    } while (n > 0);

    return digits;
};

var toString = function(n) {
    var digitArr = intToDigits(n);
    return digitArr.map(function(n) {
        return "0123456789"[n];
    }).join('');
};
```

Usage:

```
>> toString(678)
"678"
```

Comment: I tried `toString(123.123)` and got some ungodly huge number :/

Comment: Easier computation of `highestPow`: `Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(n)))`.

Comment: This doesn't take decimals into account.

Comment: @Xufox yep, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

This works for integers. It takes the number modulo 10 and divides it by 10 repeatedly, then adds 48 to the digits and uses `String.fromCharCode` to get a string value of the digits, then joins everything.

```js
function toString(n){
  var minus = (n < 0
      ? "-"
      : ""),
    result = [];
  n = Math.abs(n);
  while(n > 0){
    result.unshift(n % 10);
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  }
  return minus + (result.map(function(d){
    return String.fromCharCode(d + 48);
  })
    .join("") || "0");
}

console.log(toString(123123));
console.log(toString(999));
console.log(toString(0));
console.log(toString(-1));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using ES6 you could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
var a = 5;
console.log(`${a}`);
```

Comment: This is basically equivalent to the `123+""` method I mentioned in the question body. Not what the interviewer was looking for implementation wise

Comment: sorry man, I was thinking he wanted you to talk technically about ES versions and features.