# Number to string converstion, why +'' is the fast way to convert

Tags: javascript, performance

As I saw this question
[What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript), It seems that if there is a var 'a' typeof number, `a + ''` is the fastest way to convert to String.
And I don't know why, because in the last, a has to be called with `toString` and binary operator shouldn't be checked with the type of both operands?
So Here's question

1. Why is `a+''` the fastest way to convert a number to a string?
2. Is this the fastest way for all types or just numbers?

Comment: About the fastest way to parse numbers to strings, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: The Javascript interpreter doesn't need to call `.toString()`, it can use internal code that performs the string conversion directly. So it saves the function call overhead.

Comment: And there's no overhead from the concatenation operator, because it knows that `+ ''` doesn't need to call the concatenation function.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I also looked at the ECMA specs and was surprised to find what you said. I think there are two possibilities (incomplete ideas)
a) Using the + operator skips some steps in toString method (look at 19.1.3.6 in ECMA - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring)
b) The lookup for + is much faster than toString()