# convert number array to string array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I need to convert number array to string array in angular.

Number string(getting data from server) look like:

```
"data": [
        957,
        958,
        959,
        960,
        961,
        963
    ],
```

I need to convert into :-

```
data=["957","958","959","960","961","963"]
```

I try but don't get success. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` to iterate over array and return new array with converted values:

```
var dataNumbers = [
        957,
        958,
        959,
        960,
        961,
        963
    ];

var dataStrings = dataNumbers.map(function(value) {
 return String(value);
});

console.log(dataStrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array.

Inside the callback function you can either use `"" + o` or use `String(o)`

```js
var data= [
  957,
  958,
  959,
  960,
  961,
  963
];

console.log(data.map(o => ""+o));
console.log(data.map(o => String(o)));
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert an `int` to `string`, there are many methods. Among them `toString()` seems to be the better option. You can find other possible methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript).

So now to iterate over an array, the better method is `map()` method. The idea is iterate over each element convert that element to string.

---

Here is the working snippet for you.

```js
var data= [
  957,
  958,
  959,
  960,
  961,
  963
];

console.log(data.map(elt => String(elt)));

console.log(data.map(elt => elt.toString()));

console.log(data.map(elt => elt + ''));

console.log(data.map(elt => '' + elt));
```

---

Here is the same code using different types of iteration through loops.

```js
var data= [
  957,
  958,
  959,
  960,
  961,
  963
];

new_data = []

for (let i of data) {
  new_data.push(i.toString()); 
}

console.log(new_data);


new_data = []

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  new_data.push(data[i].toString()); 
}

console.log(new_data);
```

---

Hope this helps! :)