# Change Nan to String

Tags: javascript, tostring

I can check the validation of the number, How can I change to string in the same function?

```
hasValidPhone: function() {
    var isValidPhone = /^\+?[\d-|,|]{7,15}$/.test(this.val());
    return this.length > 0 ? isValidPhone : false;
},
```

Comment: typecast to string

Comment: Do you mean the [`toString()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
var n = 14;
n.toString();
```

or

```
var n = String(14);
```

or

```
var n = 14+"";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourVar = String(this.val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply toSring function like this -

```
var num = 15;
var n = num.toString();
```

Comment: Is there any way to be able to send you the code so you can help me? I am very new in this /Thanks

Comment: @shma1001 dude just when you get the number you just make it is as a string like say isValidPhone is your when you get it now just do isValidPhone .toString(); thats it