# angularjs-google-maps Info window position

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-google-maps

I work with  angularjs-google-maps and I used [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/na2P7Nxl9zjhWvUxRvKa?p=preview) example for my application. In the controller at `vm.shops` if I change the:

```
vm.shops = [
    {id:'1', name: 'FOO SHOP', position:[41,-87]},
    {id:'2', name: 'BAR SHOP', position:[42,-86]}
];
```

To:

```
vm.shops = [
    {id:1, name: 'FOO SHOP', position:[41,-87]},
    {id:2, name: 'BAR SHOP', position:[42,-86]}
];
```

So the id number is without `''` the info Window appears for all markers in the same position and this position is not above each marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showInfoWindow` is expecting a string, so you can use [**`toString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on `shop.id`:

```
  vm.showDetail = function(e, shop) {
    vm.shop = shop;
    vm.map.showInfoWindow('foo-iw', shop.id.toString());
  };
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4yEpvGoeCmQe2ZCpDGgF?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can [parse to string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5765401/4927984) your shop IDs in the `showDetail` function:

```
vm.map.showInfoWindow('foo-iw', shop.id + '');
```

## [Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/krl8fx9fFPFxnSH5Rjw0?p=preview)