# React Native TextInput value is not working

Tags: react-native

I have something like this:

```
<TextInput
  style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
  value={0}
  onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({ value: input })}
/>
```

However, the input box is always empty after load, any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

TextInput component only accept strings. Looks like you have a integer there. Try changing that to a string. Heres a [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#value) to the doc.

Comment: Some best ways to convert a number to string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks, tried this one and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its caused by an integer value. Do JSON.stringify(value)

Answer (score 0):

just change the `value = {this.state.value}`

```
<TextInput
  style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
  value={this.state.value}
  onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({ value: input })}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use toString()

```
<TextInput
  style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
  value={this.state.value.toString()}
  onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({ value: input })}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this it works with me!

```
    const [_employee, setEmployee]=useState(
      {
        name: "name"
        salary: 0
      })
```

.
.
.

```
    <Input
      onChangeText={(salary) =>
        (salary = parseInt(salary)) & setEmployee({ ..._employee, salary })
      }
      value={JSON.stringify(_employee.salary)}
    />
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thank you for your effort. Unfortunately, your answer is not very helpful. Please explain your answer and avoid code-only answers. To learn more, see our tips on [writing great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)