# ensure undefined in accessing object don't break the enitre app

Tags: javascript

One annoying thing about writing js app is that nested object can caused error and break down the entire app.

```
if(result.applicant._id === null || applicant_id !== result.applicant._id.toString()){
console.log('redirect user');
}
```

Given above code, it can be dangerous, what if result.applicant._id is null? then toString will be invalid because it can't be undefined.toString(). How to ensure toString() work in this case? I can do

```
if(result.applicant._id === null || applicant_id !== (result.applicant._id && result.applicant._id.toString())){}
```

but that's so unclean. I found that I'll have many duplication just for the sake of checking something exist using js.

Comment: Have you tried using `try{}catch(){}` expressions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version works without ever hitting `undefined.toString()` because the if condition will be short-circuited (short-circuitted?) as `result.applicant._id === null` would evaluate as true and never evaluate `applicant_id !== result.applicant._id.toString()`.

The test is already there no need to add extra checks in this case.

**Update** Just realised the `===` will not match `undefined`.

Just change the first part to `result.applicant._id == null` which will match `undefined` and `null`.

```
if (result.applicant._id == null || applicant_id !== result.applicant._id.toString()){
    console.log('redirect user');
}
```

I know you may end with linting warnings but in this case that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: I know linters will complain about using `==` but it is still valid to do it and is "the" way to do this. I only use `==` when needed and tend to leave a comment that that is what is intended in case someone else comes along and decides they want to kill the warning.

Comment: @JamieAden the same mater in ths case: "if applicant doesn't exist this will thrown an error too"

Answer (score 0):

A bit of short-handing might give you the cleaner code you're looking for.
As long as `0` is not a valid application id:

```
const id = result.application._id || 0;
if(!id || applicant_id !== id.toString()){
  // redirect
}
```

**Edit:** To explain - the `||` in the variable declaration assigns the value to the first `truthy` value - or the second. Therefore, if the value is undefined, it will fall to the second value (`0`) which is still falsey and will fail the check, but can still have `.toString()` called on it.

**Edit 2:** If your ids are just numbers (which is what it looks like) then you actually don't need to convert it to a string - just let JavaScript's coercion to the work for you by using `!=` instead of `!==`

```
const id = result.application._id || 0;
if(!id || applicant_id != id){
 // redirect
}
```

In JavaScript, `12 == '12'` is true. `12 === '12'` is false. Generally the advice is to use `===` unless you consciously *want* to take advantage of coercion, and this seems like a good case for it :)

Comment: using `==` is not safe and I want to avoid that.

Comment: It's not unsafe as long as you understand the difference in how it works compared to `===`. It actually serves a pretty specific purpose in JavaScript but it can be confused by programmers coming from other languages where `==` is the default operator. Coercion is a feature of JavaScript, as long as we use it where it makes sense and is intentional :)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way could be this:

**.: UPDATED :.**

```
const applicant = result.applicant || {}
if (applicant_id !== `${applicant._id}`) {
  console.log('redirect user');
}
```

Comment: if applicant doesn't exist this will thrown an error too

Comment: @JamieAden in that case we need to add `const applicant = result.applicant || {}`