# How to pass a variable to toggle a specific panel inside an accordion in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of ngbpanels generated using ngFor. I need to expand/de-expand a specific panel according to some logic, however the name I pass for the panel ID is a variable. The code does not identify the panel ID and thus does not toggle it. How can I format the variable such that it is identified.

In the html file

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" >
<ngb-panel *ngFor="let panel of panels; let panelIndex=index" id="{{panelIndex}}">
....
```

In the ts file:

```
@ViewChild('acc') panelsView;
....
this.panelsView.toggle(this.panelIndex);
```

The issue is that toggle would take a string like this: .toggle('panelId'), where panelId is the real string representing the id of the panel. The issue is that I want to pass a variable. I tried .toggle(" '+this.panelIndex+' "), but it did not work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `panelIndex: number` into a string and pass it to the `toggle()` method:

```
this.panelsView.toggle('' + this.panelIndex);
```

See a working plunkr at http://plnkr.co/edit/6K83uv54zV0PFjrt0EO4?p=preview

Source: [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript), https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api