# How do I convert a typescript enum value to string

Tags: typescript

I have an enum in typscript. I need to convert the value of the enum to string so that I can pass this to an api endpoint.  How do I do this? Thanks.

```
enum RecordStatus {
    CancelledClosed = 102830004,
    Completed = 102830003,
    InProgress = 102830002,
    ShoppingCart = 102830005,
    Submitted = 102830001,
    Unordered = 102830000
}
```

example:

```
var submittedStrValue = RecordStatus.Submitted // I want to get "10283001" (note the string value rather than the int value.
```

Comment: So, you're asking how to convert a number to a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Ok, I thought it would require doing something like RecordStatus[RecordStatus.Submitted].

Comment: @JeffreyJuarez That is if you want to get the string `Submitted`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20RecordStatus%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20CancelledClosed%20%3D%20102830004%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Completed%20%3D%20102830003%2C%0A%20%20%20%20InProgress%20%3D%20102830002%2C%0A%20%20%20%20ShoppingCart%20%3D%20102830005%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Submitted%20%3D%20102830001%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Unordered%20%3D%20102830000%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(RecordStatus.Submitted)%0Aconsole.log(RecordStatus%5BRecordStatus.Submitted%5D)

Answer (score 24):

You can just use `RecordStatus.Submitted.toString()`.

Comment: You could always use string enums too, especially if you're going to always want to use the string value, and you're going to explicitly assign a value to each enum.