# HTML shows ID instead of Name

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have created the following

```
export enum status {
    Draft = 1,
    Publish = 2,
    OnHold = 3,
    Completed = 4
}
```

In the ts file I declare it as follows and give it a default value

```
courseStatus: status = status.Draft;
```

However, in the HTML it gives me an ID when using the following:

```
<label [for]="'status'">{{courseStatus}}</label>
```

I tried adding another variable - but this still gives a number ([as per link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611942/how-do-i-convert-a-typescript-enum-value-to-string))

```
courseStatusValue: string = this.courseStatus.toString();
```

My API returns an ID.  Its this ID I want to convert into an enum value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the values you assigned to the enum:

```
export enum status {
  Draft = 'Draft',
  Publish = 'Publish',
  OnHold = 'OnHold',
  Completed = 'Completed'
}
```

Comment: hi Nijat, thanks for the input. I should have mentioned that the ID is what I get from the API.  I use the enum to map it.