# Convert array of object values from int to string

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```
 [ { "id": 1, "name": "Test" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Test2" }
```

How can I convert that to

```
 [ { "id": '1', "name": "Test" }, { "id": '2', "name": "Test2" }
```

Comment: using javascript - what have you tried?, perhaps "toString" is a start

Comment: Ideal use case of `Array#map`

Comment: map, for a new array, forEach for change in place

Comment: Please, show what have you tried so far, then provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all the objects in an array, you want to convert a property type from `number` to `string`. You can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to achieve the same.

```js
let arr = [ { "id": 1, "name": "Test" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Test2" }];
arr.forEach(v => v.id += '');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You can use toString method like ``arr.forEach(v => v.id.toString());`` It will be better performance wise.

Comment: @ImranQamer - Using `toString` is fine and is a possible alternate, but I feel that you will need to assign the value back to `v.id` as well.

Comment: Yes, You are right i missed that part, i edited my comment.

Comment: it should be ``arr.forEach(v => v.id=v.id.toString());``