# Map.get returning undefined despite value existing

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a map with the value

```
'1' => User {
    id: '1',
    username: 'Clyde',
    discriminator: '0000',
    avatar: 'https://discordapp.com/assets/f78426a064bc9dd24847519259bc42af.png',
    bot: true,
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null 
}
```

But when I get the id and try to get it using `Map.get(id);` it returns undefined and when I console.log the id variable I am using it returns `1` without the single quotes. So I am wondering how do I get the single quotes and convert it to a string so it returns the map value.

thank you

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript help?

Comment: @snak Kind of, id now logs '1' but still when I use Map.get(id) it returns undefined

Comment: Map keys are type-sensitive. Try `Map.get(String(id))` if your `id` is a number

Comment: @Phil I see - this works! thank you both so much!