# Testing if a specific sequence of numbers is somewhere in a integer javascript

Tags: javascript, integer

I know that this question was asked about in PHP but I could not find anything in javascript.

I have a random number generated between `000`(yeah it is just three zero's but it is shown that way from how the number is generated) and `999999999` and I want to test `true` or `false` for if whether it includes a specific sequence of numbers like 777, 9000, 28, or the like of any length and from any beginning of numbers...

for example, finding 289 in `678342891` or `728987699` would be `true`, and finding 289 in `678529187` or `023829564` would be `false`.

is this possible, and how would I do it?

Comment: Turn it to a string and use `.includes` ??

Comment: Plus, of course, [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5765398/215552)

Answer (score 3):

you can use [.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method in JS after transforming both the number and the other number to strings using [.toSting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-tostring-function/#:%7E:text=The%20toString()%20method%20in,representing%20the%20specified%20Number%20object.&text=The%20toString()%20method%20is,%27%20operator.) method

```js
let n = 12345589;
let sub = 55;
let sub2 = 25;


function isSeq(number, sub){
  number = number.toString(10);
  sub = sub.toString(10);
  return number.includes(sub);

}

console.log(isSeq(n, sub));
console.log(isSeq(n, sub2));
```

Comment: yes this works thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your test number is a substring in your long random number. Since you have mentioned that 000 is a value, this tells me that it is a string already(no need to call toString() for it)

```
var random=678342891;
var search1=289;
var search2=777;

console.log( random.toString().indexOf(search1.toString()) != -1 );//true

console.log( random.toString().indexOf(search2.toString()) != -1 );//false
```

A function to test it would look like so:

```
function test(random,search){
    return random.toString().indexOf(search.toString()) != -1
}
```