# shortcut symbol for converting toString

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, variables, numeric

As you know, if I want to the get numeric value of a variable (e.g. `$event`) I'd do:

```
   <ax-text-box (valueChange)='documentSearchItem.fromPrice=(+$event)'></ax-text-box>
```

I add a `+` to do that.
Is there a simple way like this, to get the string value of a variable ?
p.s. I don't want to use a method. I want to be able to use it in HTML templates.

Comment: Please describe the type or source of variable `$event`. In other words, post a [example] so we can reproduce. Numeric to String conversion is [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript): `num.toString()` or `'' + num`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @hc_dev No it does not! I want to use it in HTML template, not in JS/TS files

Comment: @Qiimiia which HTML template allows JS expressions like `+x` but not expressions like `String(x)` or `"" + x`? If `+` is *special* and only available in the templating engine you use, then you should specify *which* templating engine that is. Because the answers *have* to only target that, not a generic JS approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
let v = 2 // whatever value
let s = v.toString()
```

Comment: I don't want to use a method. I might wanna do it in an HTML template so I want a really quick and clean shortcut.

Comment: @Qiimiia Then please add this "don't want to use a method" and "for use in HTML-template" as requirement to your question. (Mentioning ghe templating-language, e.g. Angular, might help there to).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways. A short one without methods is using `template strings`:

```js
let inputNum = 222;
let newString = `${inputNum}`;
console.log(typeof(newString));
```

Comment: I want a really clean way that can be used in HTML template