# Convert an object into array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object with these key-value pairs. This object comes from an API which I am calling :

```
APIName(obj).subscribe((res:any) => {
   console.log(Object.values(res.data));
})  



data = {
   0 : 1,
   1: 3,
   2: 7,
   3: 10
....so on
}
```

[image]

simply put it is an object of numbers and my desired output is *(a simple array)* :

```
data = [1,3,7,10]
```

I've tried *Object.value* and *Object.key* it still converts it into an object. Any help?

Comment: Second result in Google; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript

Comment: `data = Object.values(data)` should work.

Comment: it's not working. I'll tell you what's exactly how it's not working.

Comment: @Shinichi - [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) works just fine for this. What specific problem did you have with it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i've edited it.

Comment: @Shinichi - *"it still converts it into an object"* Arrays **are** objects, but `Object.values` gives you an array, not just a non-array object. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ugx2dc7o/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've added the pics. Please check.

Comment: @Shinichi - The pics show that the "object" is **already** an array. There's no need to attempt to convert it further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243928/discussion-between-shinichi-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @Shinichi - I see no point in doing so. You already have an array. That's your answer. If there's further clarification you want to make, do it with an edit to the question or a comment (since it's directly related to the question, not a "discussion" -- the site feature that suggested you do that is one of the dumber things they did to the site :-) ).

Comment: Side note: The code in the question is trying to use `res.data`, but the screenshot shows `res.data.afterRelease`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , The when i checked the typeof of the variable it showed me 'Object'. That's the reason i asked was due to that. P.S I know its res.data.afterRelease I just did it for making it simple.

Comment: @Shinichi `typeof []` is indeed `"object"`. `typeof` isn't very useful, sadly. To see if something is an array, use `Array.isArray(theThing)`. MDN's reference material for JavaScript is very good: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh ok. I understood that now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Shinichi - I'm glad we figured it out! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm trying. Now I've to convert it into Array of strings i.e. data = ['1','3','7']

Comment: @Shinichi - See [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) page has lots of useful info. Then for converting numbers to strings, there are lots of questions and answers on that, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript).

Answer (score -1):

First of all if your data is not sorted by key. Then sort it. and iterate through object and push to array.

```js
var data = {
   1: 1,
   0: 3,
   2: 7,
   3: 10
};
let sortedKeys = Object.keys(data).sort();
let arrayOfData = [];
// iterate method
sortedKeys.forEach((key) => {
  arrayOfData.push(data[key]);
});
console.log(arrayOfData);
```