# Rendering single data from an array using .find()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to display single details of an object inside an array using .find() but I keep getting undefined.

Below is my code on what I was trying to do, when I log id, i get the value but when i log **service** i get undefined. what could be wrong

```
export const services = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "A good services",
    desc: "Lorem300"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Another good services",
    desc: "Lorem300"
  },
{
    id: 3,
    title: "Three good services",
    desc: "Lorem300"
  },
];
```

**Where I am trying to render the array**

```
import React from "react";

import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import { services } from "../constants";

const ServiceDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const service = services.find((item) => item.id === id);

  console.log(id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="h2 text-accent font-secondary text-[30px] lg:text-[55px]">
        {service?.title}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ServiceDetails;
```

Comment: What is `services`? Are you sure there's an object with that id in the array? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please add services as well to your question.

Comment: What is the type when you hover over id in const { id } = useParams();?

Comment: (alias) useParams<string>(): Readonly<Params<string>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting undefined even though you have the `id` in services, is because you are using triple equals `===`. This checks that the value **and** the type are the same.

In your case, `id` from params is a typeof string, and `id` in services is a typeof number. So it returns undefined.

Solution:

```js
const service = services.find((item) => item.id == id);
```

use double equals which only checks the value, **not** the type.

Answer (score -1):

useParams is returning a string value so you could try one of the following solutions:

1. Convert the value of `item.id` to string

   ```js
   const service = services.find((item) => `${item.id}` == id);
   ```

   More ways to convert to string: [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript/50730371#50730371)
2. Convert the id to type Number

   ```js
   const service = services.find((item) => item.id === Number(id));
   ```
3. Just use `==` instead of `===` since `==` will be able to match a sting number with an actual number (Ex: `1 == '1'` will be `True`).

   You can read up more here:

   - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness
   - [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)